# Getting windows only images from the IE Dev Tools site

Tags: testing, browser, modern.ie

I think this may be  website bug but when I choose VirtualBox and Mac on this page: https://dev.windows.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/vms/mac/ for anything higher than IE9 I get images for virtualbox Windows only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can safely ignore the filename. The content is exactly the same and the filename will change in a future update (hopefully sometime in January).
Source: I'm the PM of the website.

Comment: Ok, that works for sourcing. :) There's something about the current bundle that makes the default unarchive tool on my current gen, current software mac freak out and archive the file in a different format when I attempt to extract the contents. But when I used unarchiver (3rd party) it works fine. Maybe something to look into.

Comment: Files are too big and we need to use zip64 which is not supported by the Mac GUI (I believe the cmd works). We used rar files back in the day but people preferred zip files...